# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo JAVA ANDROID

Tags: java, android

Hi i get crash of apps when i load all apps,crash does not comes to me but on some other guys devices so what i do is i check all installed apps including system it works fine no issues but crash happens at "getPackageInfo"

my code below

```
public ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
        ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            boolean issystemapp = isSystemPackage(p);

            if ((!getSysPackages) && issystemapp)
                continue;
            if (p.packageName.equals(getPackageName()))
                continue;

            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
        return res;
    }

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo packageInfo) {
        return ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
    }

public List<AppInfo> getApplicationsInfo(Context context) {

        pinfos = getInstalledApps(true); // get installed user apps (true = system as well)

        List<AppInfo> apps = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();

        if (pinfos == null || pinfos.size() <= 0) {
            Log.v(TAG, "no apps..");
            return apps;
        }

        for (int ii = 0; ii < pinfos.size(); ii++) {
            AppInfo info = new AppInfo();
            // PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); (calling new pm object so transaction issue dont come so i comment it out and called seprate)

            String pkg_name = pinfos.get(ii).pname; //(package name of app)

            try {
                ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);                    // MAYBE ISSUE HERE
                ActivityInfo aInfo[] = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;       // MAYBE ISSUE HERE

                String adspresent = "ads not present";
                String internet_status = "Internet not check";

                if (aInfo != null && aInfo.length >= 1) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < aInfo.length; i++) {
                        String activityname = aInfo[i].name;
                        if (activityname.equals("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity")) {
                            adspresent = "ads present";
                        }
                    }

                }

                String[] requestedPermissions = pInfo.requestedPermissions;
                if (requestedPermissions != null) {

                    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(requestedPermissions)); // string array to array list

                    if (stringList.contains("com.android.INTERNET")) {
                        internet_status = "Internet check";
                    }

                }

                info.packageName = pkg_name;
        info.icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(ai);
                info.name = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(ai).toString();
                info.status = internet_status;
                info.ads = adspresent;
                apps.add(info);

            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return apps;
    }
```

issue seems to be due to this lines

```
PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);                    // MAYBE ISSUE HERE
ActivityInfo aInfo[] = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;       // MAYBE ISSUE HERE
```

ISSUE

```
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     ... 4 more
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.java:2252)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:133)
08-07 06:54:34.303 E/AndroidRuntime(13823):     ... 14 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:138)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:334)
08-07 06:55:24.498 E/AndroidRuntime(13878):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(<Xposed>)
```

i don't know what is wrong and how ti fix it,if you have any clue please let me know

Comment: anybody can help me ?

Comment: do you get any solution for it?